# How to set restorationIdentifier in swift?

Tags: swift

I've created a `UIView`, appended it to a `UIViewController`, and next I want to set its (`UIView`) unique identifier for next-time selection without saving `UIView` in a var.

How can I do this? I've tried `setValue` and directly changing the identifier but haven't found anything.

--updated

I find this string in docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html "You can assign restoration identifiers programmatically or in your storyboard file.", but how can i do this ???

Answer (score 3):

Simply type

```
self.restorationIdentifier = "/*name it here*/"
```

or for a view:

```
view.restorationIdentifier = "/*name it here*/"
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: wow! (sorry).

it's not worked, really. I work with activityIndicator/scrollview (simple View didn't tested, but its unusual for me). I can assign id from storyboard and work with it in code, but i CAN'T assign it from code.

p.s. maybe problem is in `Optionals` or smth else (i am realy junior in swift)

Comment: I don't know how to paste code here, http://pastebin.com/tc4UuDwJ that's what i want (it's "helper"-style func)

Comment: Ok so what happens when you do `scrollView.restorationIdentifier = ""`?

Comment: Hm, nothing happens - scrollView or ActivityIndicator - no difference. Both views are successfully appended to root-view, and they are "storyboard-like", expect tag and restorationIdentifier!

Comment: I think - may be wrap they into simple UIView. Try it now.

Comment: nothing happens. its really strange. May it be because i use static func from other file and send view as func param?

Comment: I am idiot. "return" in recursion. what a stupid day. i use this to find by restorationId - http://pastebin.com/AipPmYJJ - "return" in recursion not needed.

Comment: :D Well, at least you found the issue. Please make sure to accept my answer if it was helpful :)